# Primefaces 5.0 selectCheckboxMenu component issue, not able to close dropdown after ajex call

Tags: primefaces

PrimeFaces 5.0 selectCheckboxMenu component issue, not able to close drop down after Ajax call.

I want to update a label text with count of number of checkboxes checked in selectCheckboxMenu component.

Below is my code in .xhtml file.  After ajax call I found an error

`this.closer is undefined in primefaces.js line 22.`

```xhtml
<p:selectCheckboxMenu id="pioDocType"
                      value="#{pioReportActionBean.selectedOutPutData}"
                      label="#{pioReportActionBean.lbl_docType}" filter="true"
                      filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px"
                      styleClass="rep_checkbox" widgetVar="myCheckbox">

   <f:selectItems value="#{pioReportActionBean.inPutData}"
                  var="outPutData" itemLabel="#{outPutData.displayName}"
                  itemValue="#{outPutData.displayId}" />
    <p:ajax event="change"
            listener="#{pioReportActionBean.populateLabelDocType}"
            update="pioDocType" />

</p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

I am using Spring 3 , PrimeFaces 5.0 , JDK 7.

Comment: why are you updating the same component (pioDocType) in the change event ?

Comment: I want to update same component label value , like number of checked checkbox count.

Comment: I suggest to start from here, I mean try to delete your update and see if it works... I can't predict what's happening in your bean. but just give it a try and let me know.

Comment: Yes , after delete my update , I called ajax , I am able to close my dropdown , but it's not changing same component label value.

Comment: As I see from the other question that you have posted that you have a JS error.. my answer might solve the JS issue thus you can close the menu after all

Comment: Yes , I am able to get checkbox count , from my other question , but through ajax without update it's not showing that label changes. How can I get this label changes.

Comment: I have edited the answer their, please keep one track of your issue by having only on question .. you might want to delete this one!

Comment: In my other post I have added one query related checked all checkbox , please look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was change the version of primefaces to 5.1.RC1 (primefaces-5.1.RC1.jar)

*pom.xml:*

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
    <version>5.1.RC1</version>   
</dependency>
```