# selectCheckboxMenu unable to get count of checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, primefaces

Primefaces 5.0 selectCheckboxMenu component issue, unable to get id of checkbox in jQuery to get count of checked checkboxes.

I want to update the label text with the count of the checkboxes checked in `selectCheckboxMenu` component. I have tried both the ways

1. Ajax
2. jQuery to get checkbox id.

Below is my code in .xhtml file. After ajax call I found an error like this.closer is undefined in primefaces.js line 22.

```
  <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="pioDocType"
                        value="#{pioReportActionBean.selectedOutPutData}"
                        label="#{pioReportActionBean.lbl_docType}" filter="true"
                        filterMatchMode="startsWith" panelStyle="width:250px"  styleClass="rep_checkbox" widgetVar="myCheckbox" >
     <f:selectItems value="#{pioReportActionBean.inPutData}"
                    var="outPutData" itemLabel="#{outPutData.displayName}"
                    itemValue="#{outPutData.displayId}" />

     <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{pioReportActionBean.populateLabelDocType}"
             update="pioDocType" />

     </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
```

jQuery code ..

```
var count = $("#pioDocType input:checked").length;
alert(count);
count = $("#myCheckbox:checked").length;
alert(count);
count = $("input.rep_checkbox .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-panel .ui-selectcheckboxmenu-header .ui-chkbox-box:checked").length;
alert(count);
```

I am using spring 3 , Primefaces 5.0 , JDk 7.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Primefaces 5.0 selectCheckboxMenu component issue, not able to close dropdown after ajex call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25757611/primefaces-5-0-selectcheckboxmenu-component-issue-not-able-to-close-dropdown-af)

Comment: You're duplicating your question either edit the last one, or delete it.

Comment: Solution is working for individual checkbox check , but when I check on checkall it's not updating label text onchange event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this

```
var count = PF('myCheckbox').inputs.filter(":checked").length;
//change label
PF('myCheckbox').jq.find('.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-label').text(count + ' selected');
```

Comment: Solution is working for individual checkbox check , but when I check on checkall it's not updating label text on onchange event. I have called  onchange on selectCheckboxmenu component like onchange="docTypeChange();" javascript , but it's not calling when i click on checkall option.

Comment: How to call checkall event in javascript , I need to update label in checked all event.

Comment: @Parag I know it's a bit late but there is also a toggleSelect event available. Tried it and it works.